# A better way to say 'very different'

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, phrasing

What is a better way to say 'very different'?

Is there one word that is an extreme of 'different'?

**Example:** Person A and Person B embraced the spirit of evil in *very different* ways.

Is there a better way to structure this sentence overall?

Thanks.

Comment: Person A and Person B embraced the spirit of evil in unique ways

Comment: There are many synonyms of "different" -- contrasting, disparate, distinct, contrary, dissimilar, etc.

Comment: @Premlatha I like unique but it seems a bit too general. Unique here (seemingly) implies that they both had embraced it in a way that nobody else ever had. In this case, they are unique to each other.

Comment: As we know, unique means unlike any other. It cannot be increased, graduated or diminished. Seems that *to each other* is redundant. For one of them to have a unique way is surely enough to make them out to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They embraced the spirit of evil **in opposite ways**.

> - from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opposite) - opposite (adjective)  "diametrically different (as in nature or character)"

Comment: I like this a lot! It works in my specific case really nicely. However, it's interesting, because two things can be very different but not necessarily opposites.

Comment: Diametrically different constricts you to the same single axis of comparison. It would be more interesting if their difference were of both direction and intensity, or of both degrees of subtlety and levels of cruelty, of cleverness and brutality. One word would limit you. Your structure offers far more latitude. Build that up and out and keep them away from us.

Answer (score -1):

Dissimilar[not alike; different]or distinctive[characteristic of one person or thing, and so serving to distinguish it from others].

Comment: Please consider including a source along with the citation...